# Power Query M language syntax for text replacements in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I'm working with Power Query in Power BI and I have a table with text data that requires harmonization by replacing certain values. I also have a separate table that contains the original and replacement values. I would like to use Power Query's M language syntax to perform the text replacements and generate a harmonized table.

Here's an example of the initial table:

| id text | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1st day on m0nth |
| 2 | spmething was wrong |
| 3 | my address: London, baker str, 221b |
| 4 | strange adress |
| 5 | interesting task 4you |

And here's the table with the common replacements:

| original | replaced |
| --- | --- |
| 1st | first |
| m0nth | month |
| baker str | Baker street |
| adress | address |
| 4you | for you |
| spmething | something |

I would like to apply the replacements from the second table to the text column of the initial table, resulting in the following harmonized table:

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | first day on month |
| 2 | something was wrong |
| 3 | my address: London, Baker Street, 221b |
| 4 | strange address |
| 5 | interesting task four you |

Can someone please provide the Power Query M language syntax to achieve this? I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Thank you!

Comment: Did either of these answers solve your issue? If so, please toggle the checkmark to accept one

Answer (score 0):

You want the code that is described as slow, but for your case the best way, from https://www.thebiccountant.com/2016/05/22/multiple-replacements-in-power-bi-and-power-query/

```
let Replacements = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Replacements"]}[Content],
TextToChange = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Text"]}[Content],
WordsToReplace = List.Buffer(Replacements[Word To Replace]),
WordsToReplaceWith = List.Buffer(Replacements[Replace With]),
ReplacementFunction = (InputText)=> 
 let DoReplacement = List.Generate(
                      ()=> [Counter=0, MyText=InputText], 
                      each [Counter]<=List.Count(WordsToReplaceWith), 
                      each [Counter=[Counter]+1, 
                            MyText=Text.Replace(
                                     [MyText], 
                                     WordsToReplace{[Counter]}, 
                                     WordsToReplaceWith{[Counter]})], 
                      each [MyText]),
   GetLastValue = List.Last(DoReplacement)
 in
  GetLastValue,
Output = Table.AddColumn(TextToChange, "Changed Text List.Generate", each ReplacementFunction([Text])),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Output,{"Text"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using List.Accumulate to Transform the Text column using the Replacement list:

```
let

//Read in Replacements table
// set data type and create a List
    Source0 =Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Replacements"]}[Content], 
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source0, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source0), each {_, type text})),
    Replacements = List.Buffer(List.Zip(Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type"))),

//Read in initial table and set data types
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Initial"]}[Content],
    Initial = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"id text", Int64.Type}, {"text", type text}}),

//Transform original column using List.Accumulate to do the multiple replacements
    #"Added Custom" = Table.TransformColumns(Initial,{
        {"text", 
            (t)=> 
                List.Accumulate(
                    Replacements,
                    t,
                    (state, current)=> 
                        Text.Replace(state, current{0},current{1})), type text}})
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]