# Power BI custom function for replace

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI I import different Excel files with data from Sales Channels. In order to merge data from these files one has to have the same channel names for sales channels. So prior to merging I try to correct small differences in channel names to the same names using Power BI Replace method. Like replace "Savedesk" -> "Save Desk", "OneApp" -> "One App" ...

Since I do need to do the same thing on different files I'd like to define a custom 'cleaning/replacing' function and apply it to different columns (not to copy/paste all the same replace actions on many tables).

Is it possible to define such a custom function?

Comment: You looking for M or DAX solution?

Comment: For M see see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76765952/how-can-i-modify-this-script-to-change-each-value-rather-than-create-a-new-colu/76766020#76766020 and 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76423261/power-query-m-language-syntax-for-text-replacements-in-power-query/76423557#76423557